# setTitle text appearance

Tags: android

I'm using Theme.Dialog on one of my activities. I'm using setTitle(mMyTitle) to set the title. I would also like to set the textAppearance. How would I go about this?

I'm not sure if I can make my own title layout for this, since I'm already using Theme.Dialog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new style and extend Theme.Dialog then override what you want to change. Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyActivityDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/MyTitleStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTitleStyle" parent="@android:style/DialogWindowTitle">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/MyTextApperance</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTextApperance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.DialogWindowTitle">
         <item name="android:textColor">#ffff0000</item>
         <item name="android:textSize">36sp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Anything you don't specify will use the Dialog defaults. I've only specified the colour and font size of the textApperance in this example.

Now just use MyActivityDialogTheme (or whatever you call your style) as the theme for your activity instead of Theme.Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Check [`this`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) out first, but I believe what you're looking for is about 3/4 the way down when it discusses tweaking a built-in resource by referencing it as a parent for your custom theme. As such:

```
<color name="custom_theme_color">#b0b0ff</color>
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
</style>
```

Hope it's what you're looking for.